# Возможно ли создать динамически таблицу в БД (элементе Visual C#) в зависимости от ячеек в dataGridView?

Tags: c#, база-данных, динамические-массивы, datagridview, таблицы

То-есть, предположим есть DataGridView в котором есть данные, и пустая база данных что находится в самом проекте.

Возможно ли создать динамически таблицу, отталкиваясь от количества колонок (взяв при этом заголовки колонок за  название переменных), и заполнив при этом сразу таблицу объектами (данными из ячеек).

Как я понимаю при таком динамическом создании возможно создать таблицу только с типами переменных string, но в любом случае... Как это сделать?

Comment: Под таблицей вы имеете в виду `DataTable`?

Comment: В любом случае, процесс должен быть обратным: сперва создаётся модель данных, а потом на её основе делаются GUI-контролы.

Comment: Теоретичнски возможно, но задача не типичная, придется попотеть, то есть написать свою реализацию такого поведения с нуля. Но обычно так не делается. Вы можете динамически добавлять/удалять строки, но не колонки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov под таблицей я имею ввиду заполненный DataGridView.

Comment: В любом случае, благодарю вас за данную информацию. Буду думать теперь как решить эту проблему чутка иначе.